# SSIS 2012 Workflow Best Practices

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis, bids, ssis-2012

It is not clear to me how I should use the new features of SSIS in SQL Server 2012/2014 in an enterprise environment. Specifically, I am referring to the project deployment model, project parameters, environments, etc. We use a three-tier environment workflow; developing in development, testing and staging in QA, and production in production. The developers only have access to the development environment. The DBA’s migrate code to the other environments. All source is kept in TFS.

What is the intended workflow using these new features? If a developer develops the project/package, does the developer deploy the project to the SSISDB or does the developer stop after checking in the source? Where does the DBA come into the picture? Which environment contains SSISDB? How does the project/package get deployed to the other environments?

There seems to be many “how-to’s” published on the Internet, but I am struggling to find one that deals with the business workflow best practices. Can anyone suggest a link to an article on this subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the intended workflow using these new features?

It is up to the enterprise to determine how they will use them.

> If a developer develops the project/package, does the developer deploy the project to the SSISDB or does the developer stop after checking in the source? 
>   Where does the DBA come into the picture? Which environment contains SSISDB? How does the project/package get deployed to the other environments?

It really does depend. I advocate that developers have sysadmin rights in the development tier of servers. If they break it, they fix it (or if they've really pooched it, we re-image the server). In that scenario, they develop the implementation process and use deployments to Development to simulate the actions the DBAs will take when deploying to all the other pre-production and production environments. This generally satisfies your favorite regulatory standard (SOX/SAS70/HIPPA/CPI/etc) as those creating the work are not the same ones that install it.

What is the deliverable unit of work for SSIS packages using the project deployment model? It is an .ispac file. That is a self contained zip file with a manifest, project level parameters, project level connection managers and the SSIS packages.

How you generate that is up to you. Maybe you check the ispac in and that is what is deployed to your environments. Maybe the DBAs open the solution from source control and build their own ispac. Maybe you have Continuous Integration, CI, running and you click a button and some automated process generates and deploys the ispac.

That's 1/3 of the equation. From the SSISDB side, you likely want to create an Environment and populate it with variable values. Things like Connection Strings and file paths and user names & passwords. When you start creating those things, CLICK THE CREATE SCRIPT TO NEW WINDOW button! Otherwise, you're going to have to re-enter all that data when you lift to a new environment. I would expect your developers to check those scripts into source control. For passwords, blank out the value and make notes in your deployment checklist that they need to fix that before mashing F5.

You also need SQL Scripts to create the structure (folder) within the SSISDB for the project to be deployed into. Once deployed, you'll want to apply the Environment values, created in the preceding step, to the newly deployed project. Save those out as well.

I would have each environment contain an SSISDB. I don't want a missed configuration allowing a process in the production tier to reach across to the development tier and pull data. I've seen that, it's not pretty. When code is deployed to the QA/Stage tier, we find out quickly whether we missed a connection string somewhere because the dev servers reject the connection from QA. This means our SQL Instances don't all run under the same server account. Each tier gets their own account: domain\SQLServer_DEV, domain\SQLServer_QA, domain\SQLServer_PROD Do what you can to prevent yourself from having a bad day. If you go with a single/shared SSISDB across all your tiers, it *can* work, but you're going to have to invest a lot more energy ensuring that packages always run with the correct configuration environment applied lest bad things happen.